# How can I Remove/Hide an item in RecyclerView after '5' seconds?

Tags: android-studio, android-layout, android-recyclerview

Basically I am having two question ...I think both answer have similar approach. That's why asking both.

Part1-
I am having a RecyclerView inside a Fragment whose items are having a countdown timer and are in ascending order of the time left. **I want that after the countdown comes to Zero*** (or better say, when the countdown time expires) The ***Recyclerview should wait*** `5 seconds` ***holding the item at the top and then the Visiblity of the expired item should be invisible and the bottom item should replace its place**...
And it should be never be Visible after I start my app again.

Part2-
In this case I want  that the **expired item should go down to `bottom of the queue` of items in the recylerview**.

Note that- notifyDataSetChanged() should work properly after this.

Please help me I am trying to implement this since weeks but failing everytime.

*What I have tried is working but Whenever i open the app again or switch between fragments it shows the old Expired items, holds them for 5 seconds and then Hides them*.

This is my onBindviewHolder Method-    [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rd0rR.png [![This is the dummy Recylerview With Timer][1]][1]

````
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull Holder holder, int position) {

        UserDetail userDetail = UserArrayList.get(position);
        long timer = userDetail.getCategoryTime().toDate().getTime();
        Date today = new Date();
        final long currentTime = today.getTime();
        long expiryTime = timer - currentTime;

        new CountDownTimer(expiryTime, 1000) {
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                           //do something
                           }

            public void onFinish() {


                holder.itemView.setEnabled(false);  
                holder.ques_time_h.setText("Time up!");
                
                
   

                Handler handler = new Handler();
                handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
holder.itemView.setVisibility(View.GONE); 
                        ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = holder.itemView.getLayoutParams();
                        params.height = 0;

                    }
                }, 5000);

            }
        }.start();```
````

Answer (score 0):

Did you set **ReorderingAllowed** to true on your fragment before calling comit()?

Comment: Did ReorderingAllowed to true before commit..but still same issue

Comment: @PatrickDaligton No not working again tried it